# AspNetCore Blazor Route-Based Localization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, blazor

We're using AspNetCore 3.1 Blazor (Server-Side) on my new project, but we can't seem to get route based localization to work. (ex: domain.com/en or domain.com/nl)

We got request based localization working using the following Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddServerSideBlazor();

        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources/Localization");
        var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>{
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("nl")
        };

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("en-US");
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseRequestLocalization();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        else
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```

Is there a way within Blazor to achieve the following?:

1. Domain.com uses request based localization
2. Domain.com/en uses English localization
3. Domain.com/nl uses Dutch localization
4. Subroutes still work (ex: Domain.com/home and Domain.com/en/home)

Comment: Have you received an answer or could you develop something on your own in the meantime? We got the same questions as you do.

Comment: @Bluesight I was able to develop my own functionality. But it still isn't production worthy. A lot of bugs still appear.

Comment: We switched back to MVC and use integrated razor components..

Comment: I have exactly the same requirement for my .NET5 Blazor application. Is this solved with newer versions of .NET order maybe with the .NET6 preview?